# Obtaining index names from a by object by parsing its call

Tags: r

I'm trying to create an `as.data.frame.by` method which basically melts the N-dimensional by object for use with `latex.table.by`.

Melting it is simple enough, since a by object is just a matrix, but then the variable names returned are the most un-descriptive "X"'s imaginable.

```
dat <- transform( ChickWeight, Time=cut(Time,3), Chick=cut(as.numeric(Chick),3) )
my.by <- by( dat, with(dat,list(Time,Chick,Diet)), function(x) sum(x$weight) )
```

Looking through `attributes(my.by)` doesn't reveal anywhere the index variable names are stored except the call.  I'd like to default to something reasonably descriptive for the table.

So that leaves parsing the call:

```
> attr(my.by,"call")
by.data.frame(data = dat, INDICES = with(dat, list(Time, Chick, 
    Diet)), FUN = function(x) sum(x$weight))
> str(attr(my.by,"call"))
 language by.data.frame(data = dat, INDICES = with(dat, list(Time, Chick,      Diet)), FUN = function(x) sum(x$weight))
```

I just want the index names used, but I have no idea how to go about parsing this monster.  Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the call with named arguments you get dimnames as you expect:

```
> my.by <- with(dat, by( weight, list(Time=Time,Chick=Chick,Diet=Diet), sum ))
> str(my.by)
 by [1:3, 1:3, 1:4] 3475 5969 8002 640 1596 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
  ..$ Time : chr [1:3] "(-0.021,6.99]" "(6.99,14]" "(14,21]"
  ..$ Chick: chr [1:3] "(0.951,17.3]" "(17.3,33.7]" "(33.7,50]"
  ..$ Diet : chr [1:4] "1" "2" "3" "4"
 - attr(*, "call")= language by.default(data = weight, INDICES = list(Time = Time, Chick = Chick,      Diet = Diet), FUN = sum)
```

Comment: Nice.  Seems simple in retrospect.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This will work for the example given:

```
as.character(tail(as.list(attr(my.by, 'call')[['INDICES']]), 1) [[1]]) [-1]
```

`tail(..., 1)[[1]]` grabs the `list(Time,Chick,Diet)`, and `[-1]` drops `list`.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, the wild guess of `attr(my.by,"call")[["INDICES"]]` seems to produce a language object.

And coercing that to character works surprisingly well:

```
> as.character(attr(my.by,"call")[["INDICES"]])
[1] "with"                    "dat"                     "list(Time, Chick, Diet)"
```

So I could probably grab it from there, although it will remain highly dependent on how the user specifies it.  Better parsing ideas would be most appreciated.